# How do I change the icon, when a tab is selected X?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have a tabhost with icon, when a tab is selected X, the icon does not appear because the icon is the same color as the selected tab. The question is:

How do I change the icon, when a tab is selected X?

Answer (score 16):

This is what I have:

```
//TabActivity.onCreate()
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
TabHost.TabSpec spec;
Intent intent;

intent = new Intent().setClass(this, YourClass.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab_name").setIndicator("Tab Text",
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_dialer))
            .setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

Then, you need to add `ic_tab_dialer.xml` to `res/drawable/` directory with this content:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tab_selected_dialer" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tab_unselected_dialer" />
</selector>
```

I downloaded the icons from Contacts app GIT repo.:

git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/packages/apps/Contacts.git

Comment: Excellent! thank you so much. Just so people know, if you have tabs that do NOT lead to another activity upon clicking, you don't need the intent, the most important part is the `getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_xml_file);` I had no text in my tab, nor did I use an Intent and this works like a charm.

Comment: Good solution for me. I'm using a a TabLayout just have to set the icon with the correct drawable something like : tab1.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_one, getTheme()));